# How do I display the US flag at half staff with a standard house flag pole holder?

Tags: mounting

I recently purchased one of these (in the picture below) and a few flags to be on display.  [image]

However, how should I display the American flag at half staff?  Should I manually adjust it on the pole I have (it doesn't have pulleys to adjust it)  or should I just the lower pole location on the mount?

(Also sorry if this is in the wrong S.E. as I wasn't sure where this should belong)

Comment: FYI, in the US, 'half-staff' declarations apply specifically to government, school and military locations. A privately owned flag doesn't have to fly at half staff (though it's certainly great when it can).

Comment: Personally, I think the custom of flying a flag at half staff is a dishonor and should never be done for any reason. Also, I notice many places fly the flag at night, another dishonor that would have been unthinkable 100 years ago. This practice of lowering the flag anytime somebody dies is a modern invention which you should not feel compelled to imitate.

Comment: @TylerDurden I'm not sure how common electric power was 100 years ago, so illuminating the flag at night might have been difficult back then.

Comment: @TylerDurden a dishonor to who? A piece of material? Versus the life lost and the country mourning said life, for which the piece of material allegedly stands? I suppose you see doffing one's cap in respect as a hearse passes as a "dishonor" too? They're the same principle...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find a more 'official' site that lists this custom, but flying a black streamer with the flag is appropriate when the flag cannot physically be lowered.  This [blog posting](http://bannerisms.com/etiquette/half-staff-flag-or-black-ribbon-streamer/) is one random source, but if you search for "half mast black streamer" you get many results.

[image: Black Streamer with flag]

Possibly a more reputable source (worthiness left for you to decide):
http://www.cnn.com/2011/LIVING/05/30/fly.american.flag.mf/

Also: http://eventresources.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/How-to-Properly-Hang-the-American-Flag.pdf

> **What if I can't fly my flag at half-staff?**
>
> Some flags, like the ones commonly seen in school classrooms or on
> houses, are fixed in a certain position on their poles. How does one
> handle the sticky situation of a flag that physically can't be flown
> at half-staff? The United States Code doesn't cover this conundrum,
> but the American Legion advocates adding a black ribbon to the top of
> the flag's pole to indicate mourning.

Comment: When I was in the Air Force we used the American Legion as a source for flag info.+

Answer (score 4):

The flag is lowered by moving the pole into the lower part of the bracket so the pole is more parallel to the ground.  This is what the "chin" loop is for.  Some house brackets have a knob so a knurled bracket can be loosened, the pole lowered and then the bracket tightened to hold the flag at a lower angle.

Answer (score 0):

How is the flag presently fastened to the staff? It seems, from what I remember,  they are stapled to a 5/8 inch (?) dowel. Regardless, depending on the length of the original staff or the size of the flag, you may need a to increase the length of the dowel (or  find a smaller flag) in order to orient it at half mast. Remember the longer the dowel the easier it is to bend and the greater the force that is exerted on the bracket. Some possible material for a longer new mast might be: copper or PVC pipe, re-bar, EMT conduit, aluminum tubing, etc.